# Way to print EURO dollar sign on Linux? c++

Tags: c++

I tried:

```
#define EURO char(128)

cout << EURO ; //only worked on my windows desktop, not linux
```

Or is there a character similar to the euro sign to display ?

Comment: [Pro tip] Use characters to represent characters, not numbers.  `char euro = '€';`

Comment: `char(128) == char(-128)`, if your `char` is 8-bit.

Comment: 8-bit and signed.

Comment: It depends how your linux is configured. Modern ones are unicode by default and use UTF8 I believe.

Comment: Different terminals may be using different character encodings.

Comment: Unicode. Do you speak it?

Comment: '€' does not work on UNIX @NathanOliver

Comment: @NathanOliver I am getting: Character too large to for enclosing character type

Comment: Try `cout << "€\n";`. `€` in UTF-8 is more than one byte (`"\xE2\x82\xAC"`)

Comment: @Slava my Linux is already set to UTF8

Comment: @rustyx it works.. but this splits my cout due to the \n. So if I have a second var to display in the same line. it doesn't work.

Comment: Weird enough. It now works with "€". For some reason when I had it in my #define it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

According to this https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+20AC following should work if you Linux session configured to use UTF-8

```
std::cout << "\xe2\x82\xac" << std::endl;
```

Note it has to be a string literal not a single char as there are 3 bytes in UTF8 encoding for euro.

Comment: @Expert you asked how to print it on Linux, here is the answer. Why do you expect it to work on Windows?

Comment: was looking for a solution that could work on both.